# Problem expanding acronyms containing \hyp{} in captions

Tags: captions, hyphenation, acro

Since I performed an update of MiKTeX yesterday, acronyms containing \hyp{} do not work correctly in captions anymore. I get the following error message:

```
! Argument of \__tl_change_case_cs_four:w has an extra }.
```

The update comprised the following packages including the acro package:

```
acro.tar.lzma
beamer.tar.lzma
bidi.tar.lzma
glossaries.tar.lzma
koma-script.tar.lzma
l3kernel.tar.lzma
luamplib.tar.lzma
miktex-bibtex8bit-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-dvips-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-icu-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-pdftex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-runtime-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-texify-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-texinfo-base.tar.lzma
miktex-texinfo-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-xetex-bin-2.9.tar.lzma
```

I could drag the problem down to the usage of \hyp{} inside my acronyms. Surprisingly the problem occurs when using \Acl{...} but not when using \acl{...}. How can I fix the problem?

Here is a minimal example exposing the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\DeclareAcronym{AB}{
  short        = AB,
  %long         = a-b, % works fine
  long         = a\hyp{}b % does not work
}

\begin{document}

% works fine with hyp
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\acl{AB}}
\end{figure}

% does not work with hyp
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\Acl{AB}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Due to how `acro` works, commands like `\hyp` that are defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` don't work in that context and adding `\protect` does no good either. Switching to a different protection mechanism works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\robustify{\hyp} % make \hyp survive the capitalization process used by acro

\DeclareAcronym{AB}{
  short        = AB,
  %long         = a-b, % works fine
  long         = a\hyp{}b % does not work
}

\begin{document}

% works fine with hyp
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\acl{AB}}
\end{figure}

% does not work with hyp
\begin{figure}
  \caption{\Acl{AB}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]