# How to use the standard - (hyphen) as the \hyp{} command from the hyphenat package?

Tags: errors, compiling, hyphenation, compilation-error, hyphenat

I found this answer on http://www.oipapio.com/question-79176

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_emdash:c {---}
\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_endash:c {--}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_discardnext:NN #1#2{#1}


\catcode`\-=\active

\cs_new_protected:Npn -{
    \futurelet\hyphenfix_nexttok\hyphenfix_i:w
}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_i:w {
    \cs_if_eq:NNTF{\hyphenfix_nexttok}{-}{
        %discard the next `-` token
        \hyphenfix_discardnext:NN{\futurelet\hyphenfix_nexttok\hyphenfix_ii:w}
    }{
        % from package hyphenat
        \hyp
    }
}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_ii:w {
    \cs_if_eq:NNTF{\hyphenfix_nexttok}{-}{
        \hyphenfix_discardnext:NN{\hyphenfix_emdash:c}
    }{
        \hyphenfix_endash:c
    }
}

\begin{document}

\section{Show font}

    Tests.

    Encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding.

    Encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding.

\end{document}
```

It should allow me to use `-` as `\hyp{}` and two `--` as one `-`, but when compiling it throws this error:

```
Package: hyphenat 2009/09/02 v2.3c hyphenation utilities
\langwohyphens=\language77
LaTeX Info: Redefining \_ on input line 43.
)test1.tex:4: Undefined control sequence
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 232 strings out of 493314
```

This feature would be very welcomed because, in my language, I use a lot of `-` (hyphens) and it is horrible to keep typing (and remembering to type) `\hyp{}` everywhere.

Related questions:

1. [Adequate hyphenation of words already containing a hyphen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2706/adequate-hyphenation-of-words-already-containing-a-hyphen)
2. [Hyphenat not hyphenating words with hyphens](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/380613/hyphenat-not-hyphenating-words-with-hyphens)
3. [How to copy minus as hyphen?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/457718/how-to-copy-minus-as-hyphen)
4. [Problem expanding acronyms containing \hyp{} in captions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231078/problem-expanding-acronyms-containing-hyp-in-captions)
5. [Hyphenation problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73216/hyphenation-problem)

## Update

I managed to get it working after adding the `expl3` package. I thought it was not required. Full example:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_emdash:c {---}
\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_endash:c {--}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_discardnext:NN #1#2{#1}


\catcode`\-=\active

\cs_new_protected:Npn -{
    \futurelet\hyphenfix_nexttok\hyphenfix_i:w
}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_i:w {
    \cs_if_eq:NNTF{\hyphenfix_nexttok}{-}{
        %discard the next `-` token
        \hyphenfix_discardnext:NN{\futurelet\hyphenfix_nexttok\hyphenfix_ii:w}
    }{
        % from package hyphenat
        \hyp
    }
}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_ii:w {
    \cs_if_eq:NNTF{\hyphenfix_nexttok}{-}{
        \hyphenfix_discardnext:NN{\hyphenfix_emdash:c}
    }{
        \hyphenfix_endash:c
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Show font}

    Tests.

    Encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding.

    Encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding\hyp{}encoding.

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Now, by curiosity. Why I do not see much people using this trick everywhere else?

Does this command is breaking something in latex? Then, is it unadvised to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In german we use a shortcut provided by babel `"=` to input such hyphens. You could activate such a shortcut too, see the babel documentation.

I would never in a document activate the hyphen and use code like yours. It can explode it much too many places. Just to show two uncomment the lines marked with "error":

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_emdash:c {---}
\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_endash:c {--}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_discardnext:NN #1#2{#1}


\catcode`\-=\active

\cs_new_protected:Npn -{
    \futurelet\hyphenfix_nexttok\hyphenfix_i:w
}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_i:w {
    \cs_if_eq:NNTF{\hyphenfix_nexttok}{-}{
        %discard the next `-` token
        \hyphenfix_discardnext:NN{\futurelet\hyphenfix_nexttok\hyphenfix_ii:w}
    }{
        % from package hyphenat
        \hyp
    }
}

\cs_new:Npn \hyphenfix_ii:w {
    \cs_if_eq:NNTF{\hyphenfix_nexttok}{-}{
        \hyphenfix_discardnext:NN{\hyphenfix_emdash:c}
    }{
        \hyphenfix_endash:c
    }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{Show font}

    Tests.

    Encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding-encoding.

Encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding"=encoding.

\newlength\mylength
%\setlength\mylength{-1cm} %error

%\tikz\draw(0,0)--(1,1);   %error

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Until now I have been using the hyphenat package. But this is much easier :)

I actually found out yesterday, that there is a `\hyphen{}` command, which does basically the same as `\hyp{}` but without needing the hyphenat package. I could not find out which ressource this command is delivered from. Does anybody know?